# Bring back process after closing terminal

Tags: process

Is there a way to "reopen" a process that is running?

I accidentally closed my terminal window and it was running a openvpn. Is there a way to bring that process back to the focus of the terminal?

I've tried `fg` and `jobs` but since it is a program I don't believe those commands apply.

Comment: Have a look at `screen` and `tmux`. And you'll need to start them in advance; they don't help to bring back your closed openvpn (but they can bring back the next one).

Comment: Ya so it seems I'd have to plan in advance, but also seems openvpn doesn't work well with common solutions for bring it back to screen.

Comment: Openvpn is no different than anything else you start from the terminal in this respect... there is no "common solution" to bring back a process when the parent process has been killed.